# Error uploading a new update on Google Play

Tags: android, playback

[image: Erro uploading APK]

I have tried to rebuild the apk 5 times with diferent number of  versionCode and
        versionName, like this

```
versionCode 8
        versionName "8.0"
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic as questions regarding issues uploading updates to the Google Play Console should be asked in the relevant support forums.

Comment: Which kind of forum?

Comment: Play Console help: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer; Contact Google Play developer support page: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7218994